# QThread always stuck in wait

Tags: qt5, qthread, rhel7, qt5.11

I am trying to use `QThread` to call a function in another thread without having the UI to freeze. I am using **QT5.11.2** on both **windows** and **linux**.

Everything works fine on windows but the wait() function for `QThread` never returns no matter what.

I use **RHEL7** on linux

Here is what I am doing:

```
void MainWidget::configure_click(double value)
{
    QThread *myThread = QThread::create([this, value]{ Configure(value); });
    dsoThread->setObjectName("My Configure Thread");
    QObject::connect(myThread, &QThread::finished, [](){ qDebug()<< "Configure Thread has finished";});  //  This is never printed

    myThread->start();
    myThread->wait();  //  Never returns from this
    myThread->quit();
    myThread->deleteLater();
}
```

My `Configure` function prints its start and finish and both lines are being printed on run time

```
void MainWidget::Configure(double value)
{
    qDebug() << QThread::currentThread() << " started";
    
    //  Code to execute

    qDebug() << QThread::currentThread() << " finished";
}
```

I even read that `quit()` forces the thread to stop, so just for testing I tried switching `quit()` and `wait()` like so

```
    myThread->quit();
    myThread->wait();  //  Never returns from this either
    myThread->deleteLater();
```

I even tried looping the `isRunning()` function instead of `wait()` but I got the same results

```
    while(myThread->isRunning())  //  Same goes for !isFinished()
    {
        //  Do nothing
    }
```

It seems like no matter what the thread never knows that it was finished.

What can I do to either solve this problem or to check why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

1. You haven't `start()`ed the thread.
2. `myThread->wait();` in gui thread waits for thread to terminate so it blocks gui thread event loop, so you lose all benifints of threading this way and might as well just do `Configure(value);` without threading.

Documentation says:

> wait() and the sleep() functions should be unnecessary in
> general, since Qt is an event-driven framework. Instead of
> wait(), consider listening for the finished() signal. Instead of
> the sleep() functions, consider using QTimer.

Comment: I forgot ```start()``` when using my minimal code. But in fact I did use it. As for the blocking part when using wait(), my main focus was to use ```isRunning()``` and not wait() but I had to test it to check for the reason why it's not being finished.

Comment: I fixed the issue. If you noticed I tried to loop on ```isRunning()``` and use the ```processEvents()``` to prevent any ui blocking. This perfectly worked on windows